# How can I extract the number before "PS" (case-insensitive)?

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-match

I've a string which can look something like this:

```
)250 W (501 PS
20 ps
50 ps
LPG)                                  246 kW (334 PS
```

I want to get `501, 20, 50 and 334` respectively.
In other words: The `digit` just before `PS` OR `ps`(case insensitive).

I tired this, but doesn't work for all cases as shown above:

```
$str = 'LPG)                                  246 kW (334 PS';
preg_match('/\d+(.*?)PS/',$str, $m);
print_r($m);
```

How can I change my code to work for every possible string as shown above?

Comment: Have you tried something ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use this regex:

```
/(\d+)\s*ps/i
```

explanation:

- 1st Capturing group (\d+)
- **\d+** match a digit [0-9]

  - Quantifier: **+** Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
- **\s*** match any white space character [\r\n\t\f ]

  - Quantifier: ***** Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
- **ps** matches the characters ps literally (case insensitive)

flags:

- **i** modifier: insensitive. Case insensitive match (ignores case of [a-zA-Z])

Comment: and great explanation though.

Comment: @MubinKhalid You're welcome. (Look at your attempt again how close you were! Only the capture group around the `\d+` missed and the case-insensitivity flag, otherwise you were pretty close)

Comment: yes, I tried, but wasn't getting the results, and thanks for pointing my RE right(a bit)